# Data not being displayed in ListView on Android emulator

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I've managed to get the back end working for an android app, where it parses an RSS Feed.  However I'm having real trouble getting it to display on the GUI.  I've read many tutorials, and either I'm doing something nobody else is, or as more likely the case, I'm doing something silly, like not calling something somewhere.

The problem is, after some help for the guys who's already responded, I'm getting null pointer exceptions in my code.  I've posted teh errors below for you to take a look at.  The code hasn't changed vastly from where I've dumped it on codepad.

I'm parsing the XML using SAX if that makes a blind bit of difference.

I've dumped the pertinent files here in plain text, and sorry that they're in one massive bunch....

[Code Dump of Stuff](http://codepad.org/JgQFiUj9)

I just can't figure out where i'm going wrong.  Many thanks for your time once more.

The errors from catlog are as follows:

[CatLogErrors](http://codepad.org/hD23r10X)

Comment: post your logcat error now,,,

Comment: 02-22 03:40:20.353: E/AndroidRuntime(1512):  at WelshboyActivity.UpdateGui(WelshboyActivity.java:67)

Comment: public class WelshboyActivity extends   Activity... not ListActivity s see my answer

Comment: see my answer add  setContentView(R.layout.main);

Comment: Hi Ankit, I have now added that line, but still no change.  Sorry :(

Comment: @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        feeds = getFeed(feedSource);
        UpdateGui();
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you extend `ListActivity` and want to use your `main.xml` then you forgot to call:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

in your `onCreate()` method(before the `feeds = getFeed(feedSource);`). Also if you plan to extend `ListActivity` then in your layout you **must** have a `ListView` element with the id:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Then in your updateGui method you don't have to find the list because the `ListActivity` will automatically find it as long as you have the above `ID` :

```
private void UpdateGui() {
        ArrayAdapter<BlogPost> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<BlogPost>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, feeds);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: Hi slukian, thanks for that.  I made those changes as you suggested, and made sure everything was where it should be, but I still even now get a null pointer exception.  I'm not sure if I'm passing the wrong object at the back of the adapter or not?

Comment: It says it's a null pointer exception and then it gives a tree, and apparently it's line 67 is the first time my stuff is mentioned and then on line 40, which is the line that calls updateGUI

Comment: @Welshboy Edit your question and post the exception stacktrace from the logcat with all the red rows.

Comment: @Welshboy The `ArrayList` of blogpost that you get from the method `getFeed(String feedSrc)` is `null` because you have an `Exception` there  and then you return `null`. See exactly what exception you get when you try to parse the xml.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8088/discussion-between-welshboy-and-slukian)

Answer (score 2):

```
    public class WelshboyActivity extends   Activity 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    in UpdateGui() ,

        if(feeds.size()!=0){

        ListView itemlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);   
        ArrayAdapter<BlogPost> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<BlogPost>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, feeds);
        itemlist.setAdapter(adapter);

    }else{
         Log.d("TAG","feeds is empty ");
}
```

Comment: I did that change, however sadly, that doesn't appear to be the fix, infact it bombs when I do that...but it didn't happen before so I shall have a look.  Thanks for replying.

Comment: +1 What he said :)  You never set the adapter to the list it looks like.

Comment: Bombs how? Can you post the exception?

Comment: new info, apparently I'm getting a null pointer exception where I'm setting up the array adapter, I've changed the last bit to of that to all the stuff that pulls the RSS, but still get null pointer exceptions. :(

Comment: Your Error Log says no value in feeds List check in UpdateGui....check and debug like         for(int i=0;i<feeds.size();i++){System.out.println("Items :: " + feeds.get(i));}